# Dificuldades com ionic framework e android sdk?

Tags: android, sdk

estou começando a trabalhar com o framework ionic, e estou com algumas dificuldades na hora de construir (build) o aplicativo.
quando executo o comando

`ionic build android`

retorna o seguinte erro

`C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:483: SDK does not have any Buil Tools instaled.`

Sendo que instalei todas as opções de build-tools disponiveis no SDK manager e configurei as variáveis de ambiente exatamente como diz o tutorial do site mas mesmo assim não funciona.

Qualquer duvida com relação à pergunta estou  a disposição.

Desde já agradeço pelas respostas.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo erro parece que você não instalou (ou removeu?) o pacote `Build Tools`.

Vá até o diretório onde está instalado o SDK do Android, execute o `SDK Manager.exe` e confira se o pacote está instalado conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: Android SDK Manager]